# When post to express server after use JSON.stringify, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to send a simple array to express server as JSON, then convert it back to an object on the server side.

Client side :

```
var hand = { cards: [] }
// I randomly generate some numbers and suits and then add to the array.
var card_obj = { "number": number, "suit": suit };
hand.cards.push(card_obj)

//Send to Express server 
          var hand_json = JSON.stringify(hand)
          $.post("hand", hand_json, function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

Server side :

```
app.post("/hand", function(req, res) {
    var cards = req.body.cards
    console.log(cards[0])
});
```

This code is not working,as I receive on the server side console : **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

BUT, it will work, If i changed the client code to the following :

```
            var test = { "cards": [{ "number": "9", "suit": "club" }, { "number": "10", "suit": "club" }, { "number": "K", "suit": "spades" }, { "number": "A", "suit": "hearts" }, { "number": "5", "suit": "diamonds" }] }

            $.post("hand", test , function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

The weird thing that the test variable is the same variable generated by JSON.stringify(hand), I just copied it form the console.

I don't understand why when use JSON.stringify(hand), it doesn't work. But when copy paste the object and then pass it, it works.

Comment: Can you show the middleware you use as body parser for your server code ?

Comment: I am using bodyParser :  app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: Yes, please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a post request content `JSON` in the body you need to make sure two things:

Since you are using `JQuery`. From client, you must use `ajax` function to include a `contentType:"application/json` in your request to inform the server you are sending a JSON file:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type:"POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(hand),
  contentType:"application/json",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(result){
    `...Do something when the data returned`
  }
})
```

Now in the server, you should install and define a middleware to work as [body parser](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for your post requests

Install `npm install body-parser --save`

And use it in express

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//And make sure your route is placed below the parser
app.post("/hand", function(req, res) {
    var cards = req.body.cards
    console.log(cards[0])
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan, I am already using bodyParser, and it does work using ajax. However, when I tried to remove the bodyParser and use app.use(express.json()), it also works! My question is, why it doesn't work when I was using JQuery.

Comment: Updated answer, you need to provide a data type in your request to infor you are sending a json

Comment: It doesn't work, the object is undefined on the server. I also tried to use the body-parser, but doesn't work.

Comment: I suggest to add again your previous answer, because it works! I will use ajax for now, but I am still interested to know the answer for JQuery.

Comment: yeah, im trying to figure it too, would let you know if i find the correct solution for $.post(). As far as i know, $.post() does not support sending json